# How can I pivot a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot, pivot-table

- What is pivot?
- How do I pivot?
- Long format to wide format?

I've seen a lot of questions that ask about pivot tables, even if they don't know it.  It is virtually impossible to write a [canonical question and answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) that encompasses all aspects of pivoting... But I'm going to give it a go.

---

The problem with existing questions and answers is that often the question is focused on a nuance that the OP has trouble generalizing in order to use a number of the existing good answers.  However, none of the answers attempt to give a comprehensive explanation (because it's a daunting task). Look at a few examples from my [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20pivot%20a%20pandas%20dataframe&oq=How%20do%20I%20pivot%20a%20pandas%20dataframe):

1. [How to pivot a dataframe in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28337117/2336654) - Good question and answer.  But the answer only answers the specific question with little explanation.
2. [pandas pivot table to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42708193/2336654) - OP is concerned with the output of the pivot, namely how the columns look.  OP wanted it to look like R.  This isn't very helpful for pandas users.
3. [pandas pivoting a dataframe, duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11400181/2336654) - Another decent question but the answer focuses on one method, namely `pd.DataFrame.pivot`

---

### Setup

I conspicuously named my columns and relevant column values to correspond with how I'm going to pivot in the answers below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.core.defchararray import add

np.random.seed([3,1415])
n = 20

cols = np.array(['key', 'row', 'item', 'col'])
arr1 = (np.random.randint(5, size=(n, 4)) // [2, 1, 2, 1]).astype(str)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    add(cols, arr1), columns=cols
).join(
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n, 2).round(2)).add_prefix('val')
)
print(df)
```

```
     key   row   item   col  val0  val1
0   key0  row3  item1  col3  0.81  0.04
1   key1  row2  item1  col2  0.44  0.07
2   key1  row0  item1  col0  0.77  0.01
3   key0  row4  item0  col2  0.15  0.59
4   key1  row0  item2  col1  0.81  0.64
5   key1  row2  item2  col4  0.13  0.88
6   key2  row4  item1  col3  0.88  0.39
7   key1  row4  item1  col1  0.10  0.07
8   key1  row0  item2  col4  0.65  0.02
9   key1  row2  item0  col2  0.35  0.61
10  key2  row0  item2  col1  0.40  0.85
11  key2  row4  item1  col2  0.64  0.25
12  key0  row2  item2  col3  0.50  0.44
13  key0  row4  item1  col4  0.24  0.46
14  key1  row3  item2  col3  0.28  0.11
15  key0  row3  item1  col1  0.31  0.23
16  key0  row0  item2  col3  0.86  0.01
17  key0  row4  item0  col3  0.64  0.21
18  key2  row2  item2  col0  0.13  0.45
19  key0  row2  item0  col4  0.37  0.70
```

#### Questions

1. Why do I get `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`?
2. How do I pivot `df` such that the `col` values are columns, `row` values are the index, and mean of `val0` are the values?

   ```
   col   col0   col1   col2   col3  col4
   row
   row0  0.77  0.605    NaN  0.860  0.65
   row2  0.13    NaN  0.395  0.500  0.25
   row3   NaN  0.310    NaN  0.545   NaN
   row4   NaN  0.100  0.395  0.760  0.24
   ```
3. How do I make it so that missing values are `0`?

   ```
   col   col0   col1   col2   col3  col4
   row
   row0  0.77  0.605  0.000  0.860  0.65
   row2  0.13  0.000  0.395  0.500  0.25
   row3  0.00  0.310  0.000  0.545  0.00
   row4  0.00  0.100  0.395  0.760  0.24
   ```
4. Can I get something other than `mean`, like maybe `sum`?

   ```
   col   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
   row
   row0  0.77  1.21  0.00  0.86  0.65
   row2  0.13  0.00  0.79  0.50  0.50
   row3  0.00  0.31  0.00  1.09  0.00
   row4  0.00  0.10  0.79  1.52  0.24
   ```
5. Can I do more that one aggregation at a time?

   ```
          sum                          mean
   col   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col0   col1   col2   col3  col4
   row
   row0  0.77  1.21  0.00  0.86  0.65  0.77  0.605  0.000  0.860  0.65
   row2  0.13  0.00  0.79  0.50  0.50  0.13  0.000  0.395  0.500  0.25
   row3  0.00  0.31  0.00  1.09  0.00  0.00  0.310  0.000  0.545  0.00
   row4  0.00  0.10  0.79  1.52  0.24  0.00  0.100  0.395  0.760  0.24
   ```
6. Can I aggregate over multiple value columns?

   ```
         val0                             val1
   col   col0   col1   col2   col3  col4  col0   col1  col2   col3  col4
   row
   row0  0.77  0.605  0.000  0.860  0.65  0.01  0.745  0.00  0.010  0.02
   row2  0.13  0.000  0.395  0.500  0.25  0.45  0.000  0.34  0.440  0.79
   row3  0.00  0.310  0.000  0.545  0.00  0.00  0.230  0.00  0.075  0.00
   row4  0.00  0.100  0.395  0.760  0.24  0.00  0.070  0.42  0.300  0.46
   ```
7. Can I subdivide by multiple columns?

   ```
   item item0             item1                         item2
   col   col2  col3  col4  col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col0   col1  col3  col4
   row
   row0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.77  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.605  0.86  0.65
   row2  0.35  0.00  0.37  0.00  0.00  0.44  0.00  0.00  0.13  0.000  0.50  0.13
   row3  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.31  0.00  0.81  0.00  0.00  0.000  0.28  0.00
   row4  0.15  0.64  0.00  0.00  0.10  0.64  0.88  0.24  0.00  0.000  0.00  0.00
   ```
8. Or

   ```
   item      item0             item1                         item2
   col        col2  col3  col4  col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col0  col1  col3  col4
   key  row
   key0 row0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.86  0.00
        row2  0.00  0.00  0.37  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.50  0.00
        row3  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.31  0.00  0.81  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
        row4  0.15  0.64  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.24  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
   key1 row0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.77  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.81  0.00  0.65
        row2  0.35  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.44  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.13
        row3  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.28  0.00
        row4  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.10  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
   key2 row0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.40  0.00  0.00
        row2  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.13  0.00  0.00  0.00
        row4  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.64  0.88  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
   ```
9. Can I aggregate the frequency in which the column and rows occur together, aka "cross tabulation"?

   ```
   col   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
   row
   row0     1     2     0     1     1
   row2     1     0     2     1     2
   row3     0     1     0     2     0
   row4     0     1     2     2     1
   ```
10. How do I convert a DataFrame from long to wide by pivoting on ONLY two columns? Given,

    ```
    np.random.seed([3, 1415])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aaaabbbc'), 'B': np.random.choice(15, 8)})
    df2
       A   B
    0  a   0
    1  a  11
    2  a   2
    3  a  11
    4  b  10
    5  b  10
    6  b  14
    7  c   7
    ```

    The expected should look something like

    ```
          a     b    c
    0   0.0  10.0  7.0
    1  11.0  10.0  NaN
    2   2.0  14.0  NaN
    3  11.0   NaN  NaN
    ```
11. How do I flatten the multiple index to single index after `pivot`?

    From

    ```
       1  2
       1  1  2
    a  2  1  1
    b  2  1  0
    c  1  0  0
    ```

    To

    ```
       1|1  2|1  2|2
    a    2    1    1
    b    2    1    0
    c    1    0    0
    ```

Comment: Very helpful question! A small suggestion: would it not be more suitable to split these question up into several posts? I had a problem similar to question 8, but did not find it here after a short a glance. Only after I created a (now marked as duplicate) question I was redirected here again and found the solution I needed.

Comment: IMHO, this is too broad to be a good canonical question, and it should be broken up. I'm not a Pandas expert, but my intuition is that questions 2-6 should be kept here, while questions 1, 7-8, 9, 10, and 11 should all be separate. But by all means use the same example data and link them to each other. I'm open to discussing this on Meta.

Comment: @wjandrea the question shouldn't be preceded by lengthy meta commentary on the need for having such a canonical. Ideally, all of this would happen on Meta, but you can't get SMEs to congregate there and have a discussion; plus the format is not suited to that kind of discussion. We really need some kind of environment where people can collaborate on a Markdown document in real time while also chatting.

Answer (score 474, accepted):

Here is a list of idioms we can use to pivot

1. [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

   - A glorified version of `groupby` with more intuitive API.  For many people, this is the preferred approach.  And it is the intended approach by the developers.
   - Specify row level, column levels, values to be aggregated, and function(s) to perform aggregations.
2. [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`pd.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

   - Good general approach for doing just about any type of pivot
   - You specify all columns that will constitute the pivoted row levels and column levels in one group by.  You follow that by selecting the remaining columns you want to aggregate and the function(s) you want to perform the aggregation.  Finally, you `unstack` the levels that you want to be in the column index.
3. [`pd.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`pd.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

   - Convenient and intuitive for some (myself included).  Cannot handle duplicate grouped keys.
   - Similar to the `groupby` paradigm, we specify all columns that will eventually be either row or column levels and set those to be the index.  We then `unstack` the levels we want in the columns.  If either the remaining index levels or column levels are not unique, this method will fail.
4. [`pd.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

   - Very similar to `set_index` in that it shares the duplicate key limitation.  The API is very limited as well.  It only takes scalar values for `index`, `columns`, `values`.
   - Similar to the `pivot_table` method in that we select rows, columns, and values on which to pivot.  However, we cannot aggregate and if either rows or columns are not unique, this method will fail.
5. [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

   - This a specialized version of `pivot_table` and in its purest form is the most intuitive way to perform several tasks.
6. [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) + [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)

   - This is a highly advanced technique that is very obscure but is very fast.  It cannot be used in all circumstances, but when it can be used and you are comfortable using it, you will reap the performance rewards.
7. [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) + [`pd.DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html)

   - I use this for cleverly performing cross tabulation.

See also:

- [Reshaping and pivot tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html) — pandas User Guide

---

#### Question 1

> Why do I get `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

This occurs because pandas is attempting to reindex either a `columns` or `index` object with duplicate entries.  There are varying methods to use that can perform a pivot.  Some of them are not well suited to when there are duplicates of the keys on which it is being asked to pivot.  For example:  Consider `pd.DataFrame.pivot`.  I know there are duplicate entries that share the `row` and `col` values:

```
df.duplicated(['row', 'col']).any()

True
```

So when I `pivot` using

```
df.pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='val0')
```

I get the error mentioned above.  In fact, I get the same error when I try to perform the same task with:

```
df.set_index(['row', 'col'])['val0'].unstack()
```

---

### Examples

What I'm going to do for each subsequent question is to answer it using [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).  Then I'll provide alternatives to perform the same task.

#### Questions 2 and 3

> How do I pivot `df` such that the `col` values are columns, `row` values are the index, and mean of `val0` are the values?

- [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

  ```
  df.pivot_table(
      values='val0', index='row', columns='col',
      aggfunc='mean')

  col   col0   col1   col2   col3  col4
  row                                  
  row0  0.77  0.605    NaN  0.860  0.65
  row2  0.13    NaN  0.395  0.500  0.25
  row3   NaN  0.310    NaN  0.545   NaN
  row4   NaN  0.100  0.395  0.760  0.24
  ```

  - `aggfunc='mean'` is the default and I didn't have to set it.  I included it to be explicit.

> How do I make it so that missing values are 0?

- [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

  - `fill_value` is not set by default.  I tend to set it appropriately.  In this case I set it to `0`.

  ```
  df.pivot_table(
      values='val0', index='row', columns='col',
      fill_value=0, aggfunc='mean')

  col   col0   col1   col2   col3  col4
  row
  row0  0.77  0.605  0.000  0.860  0.65
  row2  0.13  0.000  0.395  0.500  0.25
  row3  0.00  0.310  0.000  0.545  0.00
  row4  0.00  0.100  0.395  0.760  0.24
  ```
- [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

  ```
  df.groupby(['row', 'col'])['val0'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
  ```
- [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

  ```
  pd.crosstab(
      index=df['row'], columns=df['col'],
      values=df['val0'], aggfunc='mean').fillna(0)
  ```

---

#### Question 4

> Can I get something other than `mean`, like maybe `sum`?

- [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

  ```
  df.pivot_table(
      values='val0', index='row', columns='col',
      fill_value=0, aggfunc='sum')

  col   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
  row
  row0  0.77  1.21  0.00  0.86  0.65
  row2  0.13  0.00  0.79  0.50  0.50
  row3  0.00  0.31  0.00  1.09  0.00
  row4  0.00  0.10  0.79  1.52  0.24
  ```
- [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

  ```
  df.groupby(['row', 'col'])['val0'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
  ```
- [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

  ```
  pd.crosstab(
      index=df['row'], columns=df['col'],
      values=df['val0'], aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
  ```

---

#### Question 5

> Can I do more that one aggregation at a time?

Notice that for `pivot_table` and `crosstab` I needed to pass list of callables.  On the other hand, `groupby.agg` is able to take strings for a limited number of special functions.  `groupby.agg` would also have taken the same callables we passed to the others, but it is often more efficient to leverage the string function names as there are efficiencies to be gained.

- [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

  ```
  df.pivot_table(
      values='val0', index='row', columns='col',
      fill_value=0, aggfunc=[np.size, np.mean])

       size                      mean
  col  col0 col1 col2 col3 col4  col0   col1   col2   col3  col4
  row
  row0    1    2    0    1    1  0.77  0.605  0.000  0.860  0.65
  row2    1    0    2    1    2  0.13  0.000  0.395  0.500  0.25
  row3    0    1    0    2    0  0.00  0.310  0.000  0.545  0.00
  row4    0    1    2    2    1  0.00  0.100  0.395  0.760  0.24
  ```
- [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

  ```
  df.groupby(['row', 'col'])['val0'].agg(['size', 'mean']).unstack(fill_value=0)
  ```
- [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

  ```
  pd.crosstab(
      index=df['row'], columns=df['col'],
      values=df['val0'], aggfunc=[np.size, np.mean]).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
  ```

---

#### Question 6

> Can I aggregate over multiple value columns?

- [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) we pass `values=['val0', 'val1']` but we could've left that off completely

  ```
  df.pivot_table(
      values=['val0', 'val1'], index='row', columns='col',
      fill_value=0, aggfunc='mean')

        val0                             val1
  col   col0   col1   col2   col3  col4  col0   col1  col2   col3  col4
  row
  row0  0.77  0.605  0.000  0.860  0.65  0.01  0.745  0.00  0.010  0.02
  row2  0.13  0.000  0.395  0.500  0.25  0.45  0.000  0.34  0.440  0.79
  row3  0.00  0.310  0.000  0.545  0.00  0.00  0.230  0.00  0.075  0.00
  row4  0.00  0.100  0.395  0.760  0.24  0.00  0.070  0.42  0.300  0.46
  ```
- [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

  ```
  df.groupby(['row', 'col'])['val0', 'val1'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
  ```

---

#### Question 7

> Can I subdivide by multiple columns?

- [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

  ```
  df.pivot_table(
      values='val0', index='row', columns=['item', 'col'],
      fill_value=0, aggfunc='mean')

  item item0             item1                         item2
  col   col2  col3  col4  col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col0   col1  col3  col4
  row
  row0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.77  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.605  0.86  0.65
  row2  0.35  0.00  0.37  0.00  0.00  0.44  0.00  0.00  0.13  0.000  0.50  0.13
  row3  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.31  0.00  0.81  0.00  0.00  0.000  0.28  0.00
  row4  0.15  0.64  0.00  0.00  0.10  0.64  0.88  0.24  0.00  0.000  0.00  0.00
  ```
- [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

  ```
  df.groupby(
      ['row', 'item', 'col']
  )['val0'].mean().unstack(['item', 'col']).fillna(0).sort_index(1)
  ```

---

#### Question 8

> Can I subdivide by multiple columns?

- [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

  ```
  df.pivot_table(
      values='val0', index=['key', 'row'], columns=['item', 'col'],
      fill_value=0, aggfunc='mean')

  item      item0             item1                         item2
  col        col2  col3  col4  col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col0  col1  col3  col4
  key  row
  key0 row0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.86  0.00
       row2  0.00  0.00  0.37  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.50  0.00
       row3  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.31  0.00  0.81  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
       row4  0.15  0.64  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.24  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
  key1 row0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.77  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.81  0.00  0.65
       row2  0.35  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.44  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.13
       row3  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.28  0.00
       row4  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.10  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
  key2 row0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.40  0.00  0.00
       row2  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.13  0.00  0.00  0.00
       row4  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.64  0.88  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
  ```
- [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

  ```
  df.groupby(
      ['key', 'row', 'item', 'col']
  )['val0'].mean().unstack(['item', 'col']).fillna(0).sort_index(1)
  ```
- [`pd.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) because the set of keys are unique for both rows and columns

  ```
  df.set_index(
      ['key', 'row', 'item', 'col']
  )['val0'].unstack(['item', 'col']).fillna(0).sort_index(1)
  ```

---

#### Question 9

> Can I aggregate the frequency in which the column and rows occur together, aka "cross tabulation"?

- [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

  ```
  df.pivot_table(index='row', columns='col', fill_value=0, aggfunc='size')

  col   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
  row
  row0     1     2     0     1     1
  row2     1     0     2     1     2
  row3     0     1     0     2     0
  row4     0     1     2     2     1
  ```
- [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

  ```
  df.groupby(['row', 'col'])['val0'].size().unstack(fill_value=0)
  ```
- [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

  ```
  pd.crosstab(df['row'], df['col'])
  ```
- [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) + [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)

  ```
  # get integer factorization `i` and unique values `r`
  # for column `'row'`
  i, r = pd.factorize(df['row'].values)
  # get integer factorization `j` and unique values `c`
  # for column `'col'`
  j, c = pd.factorize(df['col'].values)
  # `n` will be the number of rows
  # `m` will be the number of columns
  n, m = r.size, c.size
  # `i * m + j` is a clever way of counting the
  # factorization bins assuming a flat array of length
  # `n * m`.  Which is why we subsequently reshape as `(n, m)`
  b = np.bincount(i * m + j, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m)
  # BTW, whenever I read this, I think 'Bean, Rice, and Cheese'
  pd.DataFrame(b, r, c)

        col3  col2  col0  col1  col4
  row3     2     0     0     1     0
  row2     1     2     1     0     2
  row0     1     0     1     2     1
  row4     2     2     0     1     1
  ```
- [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

  ```
  pd.get_dummies(df['row']).T.dot(pd.get_dummies(df['col']))

        col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
  row0     1     2     0     1     1
  row2     1     0     2     1     2
  row3     0     1     0     2     0
  row4     0     1     2     2     1
  ```

---

#### Question 10

> How do I convert a DataFrame from long to wide by pivoting on ONLY two
> columns?

- [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

  The first step is to assign a number to each row - this number will be the row index of that value in the pivoted result. This is done using [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

  ```
  df2.insert(0, 'count', df2.groupby('A').cumcount())
  df2

     count  A   B
  0      0  a   0
  1      1  a  11
  2      2  a   2
  3      3  a  11
  4      0  b  10
  5      1  b  10
  6      2  b  14
  7      0  c   7
  ```

  The second step is to use the newly created column as the index to call [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

  ```
  df2.pivot(*df2)
  # df2.pivot(index='count', columns='A', values='B')

  A         a     b    c
  count
  0       0.0  10.0  7.0
  1      11.0  10.0  NaN
  2       2.0  14.0  NaN
  3      11.0   NaN  NaN
  ```
- [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

  Whereas [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) only accepts columns, [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) also accepts arrays, so the `GroupBy.cumcount` can be passed directly as the `index` without creating an explicit column.

  ```
  df2.pivot_table(index=df2.groupby('A').cumcount(), columns='A', values='B')

  A         a     b    c
  0       0.0  10.0  7.0
  1      11.0  10.0  NaN
  2       2.0  14.0  NaN
  3      11.0   NaN  NaN
  ```

---

#### Question 11

> How do I flatten the multiple index to single index after `pivot`

If `columns` type `object` with string `join`

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('|'.join)
```

else `format`

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}|{0[1]}'.format)
```

Comment: `pivot_table()` and `crosstab()` can take string function names now, though I'm not sure when it changed since it's not documented very clearly. I'm using Pandas 1.4.4.

Answer (score 24):

To extend [@piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47152692/12416453) another version of **[Question 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62218881/how-to-transpose-a-specif-column-from-a-dataframe-and-group-by-python)**

#### Question 10.1

DataFrame:

```
d = data = {'A': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 5},
 'B': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'a', 4: 'b', 5: 'a', 6: 'c'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

   A  B
0  1  a
1  1  b
2  1  c
3  2  a
4  2  b
5  3  a
6  5  c
```

Output:

```
   0     1     2
A
1  a     b     c
2  a     b  None
3  a  None  None
5  c  None  None
```

---

Using [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pd.Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html?highlight=series%20tolist#pandas.Series.tolist)

```
t = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list)
out = pd.DataFrame(t.tolist(),index=t.index)
out
   0     1     2
A
1  a     b     c
2  a     b  None
3  a  None  None
5  c  None  None
```

Or 
A much better alternative using [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`df.squeeze.`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html)

```
t = df.pivot_table(index='A',values='B',aggfunc=list).squeeze()
out = pd.DataFrame(t.tolist(),index=t.index)
```

Answer (score 16):

To better understand how the function [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html#pandas.pivot) works you can look at the [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects) from Pandas documentation. However `pivot` will fail if you have repeating index-columns (`foo`-`bar`) combinations (like `df` in the second example):

[image: pivot]

In opposite to `pivot` the function [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) supports data aggregation using the `mean` function by default. Here is an example with the `sum` aggregation function:

[image: pivot_table]

Answer (score 7):

##### Call `reset_index()` (along with `add_suffix()`)

Oftentimes, `reset_index()` is needed after you call `pivot_table` or `pivot`. For example, to make the following transformation (where one column *become* column names)

[image: res]

you use the following code, where after `pivot`, you add prefix to the newly created column names and convert the index (in this case `"movies"`) back into a column and remove the name of the axis name:

```py
df.pivot(index='movie', columns='week', values='sales').add_prefix('week_').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
```

---

As the other answers mentioned, "pivot" may refer to 2 different operations:

1. Unstacked aggregation (i.e. make the results of `groupby.agg` wider.)
2. Reshaping (similar to pivot in Excel, `reshape` in numpy or `pivot_wider` in R)

##### 1. Aggregation

`pivot_table` or `crosstab` are simply unstacked results of `groupby.agg` operation. In fact, the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py) shows that, under the hood, the following are true:

- `pivot_table` = `groupby` + `unstack` ([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72933069/19123103) for more info.)
- `crosstab` = `pivot_table`

N.B. You can use list of column names as `index`, `columns` and `values` arguments.

```py
df.groupby(rows+cols)[vals].agg(aggfuncs).unstack(cols)
# equivalently,
df.pivot_table(vals, rows, cols, aggfuncs)
```

###### 1.1. `crosstab` is a special case of `pivot_table`; thus of `groupby` + `unstack`

The following are equivalent:

- `pd.crosstab(df['colA'], df['colB'])`
- `df.pivot_table(index='colA', columns='colB', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)`
- `df.groupby(['colA', 'colB']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)`

Note that `pd.crosstab` has a significantly larger overhead, so it's significantly slower than both `pivot_table` and `groupby` + `unstack`. In fact, as [noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44229489/19123103), `pivot_table` is slower than `groupby` + `unstack` as well.

##### 2. Reshaping

`pivot` is a more limited version of `pivot_table` where its purpose is to reshape a long dataframe into a long one.

```py
df.set_index(rows+cols)[vals].unstack(cols)
# equivalently, 
df.pivot(index=rows, columns=cols, values=vals)
```

###### 2.1. Augment rows/columns as in Question 10

You can also apply the insight from Question 10 to multi-column pivot operation as well. There are two cases:

- **"long-to-long"**: reshape by augmenting the indices

  [image: case1]

  Code:

  ```py
  df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'B': [*'xxyyzz'], 
                     'C': [*'CCDCDD'], 'E': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})
  rows, cols, vals = ['A', 'B'], ['C'], 'E'

  # using pivot syntax
  df1 = (
      df.assign(ix=df.groupby(rows+cols).cumcount())
      .pivot(index=[*rows, 'ix'], columns=cols, values=vals)
      .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
      .droplevel(-1).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
  )

  # equivalently, using set_index + unstack syntax
  df1 = (
      df
      .set_index([*rows, df.groupby(rows+cols).cumcount(), *cols])[vals]
      .unstack(fill_value=0)
      .droplevel(-1).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
  )
  ```
- **"long-to-wide"**: reshape by augmenting the columns

  [image: case2]

  Code:

  ```py
  df1 = (
      df.assign(ix=df.groupby(rows+cols).cumcount())
      .pivot(index=rows, columns=[*cols, 'ix'])[vals]
      .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
  )
  df1 = df1.set_axis([f"{c[0]}_{c[1]}" for c in df1], axis=1).reset_index()

  # equivalently, using the set_index + unstack syntax
  df1 = (
      df
      .set_index([*rows, df.groupby(rows+cols).cumcount(), *cols])[vals]
      .unstack([-1, *range(-2, -len(cols)-2, -1)], fill_value=0)
  )
  df1 = df1.set_axis([f"{c[0]}_{c[1]}" for c in df1], axis=1).reset_index()
  ```
- minimum case using the `set_index` + `unstack` syntax:

  [image: case3]

  Code:

  ```py
  df1 = df.set_index(['A', df.groupby('A').cumcount()])['E'].unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('Col').reset_index()
  ```

---

<sup>1</sup> `pivot_table()` aggregates the values and unstacks it. Specifically, it creates a single flat list out of index and columns, calls `groupby()` with this list as the grouper and aggregates using the passed aggregator methods (the default is `mean`). Then after aggregation, it calls `unstack()` by the list of columns. So internally, **pivot_table = groupby + unstack**. Moreover, if `fill_value` is passed, `fillna()` is called.

In other words, the method that produces `pv_1` is the same as the method that produces `gb_1` in the example below.

```py
pv_1 = df.pivot_table(index=rows, columns=cols, values=vals, aggfunc=aggfuncs, fill_value=0)
# internal operation of `pivot_table()`
gb_1 = df.groupby(rows+cols)[vals].agg(aggfuncs).unstack(cols).fillna(0, downcast="infer")
pv_1.equals(gb_1) # True
```

<sup>2</sup> `crosstab()` calls `pivot_table()`, i.e., **crosstab = pivot_table**. Specifically, it builds a DataFrame out of the passed arrays of values, filters it by the common indices and calls `pivot_table()`. It's more limited than `pivot_table()` because it only allows a one-dimensional array-like as `values`, unlike `pivot_table()` that can have multiple columns as `values`.

Answer (score 4):

The pivot function in pandas has the same functionality as the pivot operation in excel. We can transform a dataset from a long format to a wide format.

[image]

Lets have a example

[image]

We want to convert the dataset into a form such that each country becomes a column and the new confirmed cases as values corresponding to the countries. We can perform this data manipulation using the pivot function.

[image]

#### Pivot the dataset

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot(df, index =['Date'], columns ='Country', values =['NewConfirmed'])
## renaming the columns  
pivot_df.columns = df['Country'].sort_values().unique()
```

We can bring the new columns to the same level as the index column Data by resetting the index.

### reset the index to modify the column levels

pivot_df = pivot_df.reset_index()

[image]

Comment: I get index Date contains duplicate values error. How to handle that?